# Sounds in a Python Program

Tags: audio

I have a simple program to find a number in a number guessing game. I would like to insert some sound like "your number is too high" into the program. I can record the phase but what do I insert into the program to play the phase?

Comment: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/gpio-music-box

Comment: Welcome -- but general python programming questions belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) .

Comment: you can use Rpi python compatible "text to speech" library functions.